# Working with session cookies in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get access to the Kerio Connect (mailserver) api which uses jsonrpc as a standard for their api.

There is `Session.login` method that works just fine, I get back a SESSION_CONNECT_WEBADMIN cookie that gets saved in the session:

```
SESSION_CONNECT_WEBADMIN=2332a56d0203f27972ebbe74c09a7f41262e5b224bc6a05e53e62e5872e9b698; \
path=/admin/; domain=<server>; Secure; HttpOnly; Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT;
```

But when I then do my next request with the same session, I get back a message that tells me, that my session has expired:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 2,
  "error": {
    "code": -32001,
    "message": "Session expired.",
    "data": {
      "messageParameters": {
        "positionalParameters": [],
        "plurality": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So here's the Python script leading to that message

```
import json
import requests

userName = "username"
password = "password"

n=1

application = {}
application["name"] = "Log in"
application["vendor"] = "My Company"
application["version"] = "1.0"

params = {}
params["userName"] = userName
params["password"] = password
params["application"] = application

payload = {}
payload["jsonrpc"] = "2.0"
payload["id"] = n
n += 1
payload["method"] = "Session.login"
payload["params"] = params

headers = {}
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json-rpc"

json_payload =json.dumps(payload, sort_keys=True, indent=2)

url = "https://<server>:4040/admin/api/jsonrpc/"

session = requests.Session()

response = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=json_payload, verify=False)
# Results in a token / a cookie with that token

payload2 = {}
payload2["jsonrpc"] = "2.0"
payload2["id"] = n
n += 1
payload2["method"] = "Users.get"

json_payload2 = json.dumps(payload2, sort_keys=True, indent=2)

response2 = session.post(url, data=json_payload2, verify=False)
print(response2.text)
```

What am I missing here because of my lack of experience?

[EDIT]:
I just now realise that when I log in with a browser, two cookies are actually created, each with another token, whereas I get only one cookie back when I try to access the api with Python. Why is that?

- Cookies received with Chrome:

  - TOKEN_CONNECT_WEBADMIN
  - SESSION_CONNECT_WEBADMIN
- Cookie received with Python:

  - SESSION_CONNECT_WEBADMIN

Comment: Just found out about a difference to when logging in with a browser; I get 2 cookies than (see my edit). Do I have to tweak my request in a way that I obtain the 2nd cookie as well?

Comment: You can try attaching all headers your browser sent to your request

Comment: Guess you are right, thanks for the input.
Seems as though it's doing a second request with the token it receives in order to retrieve that 2nd cookie...
Will have to do some more digging with the Chrome dev tools to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
import json
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar
import ssl


jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
server = "https://mail.smkh.ru:4040"
username = "admin"
password = "pass"

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context  # disable ssl cert error

def callMethod(method, params, token=None):
    """
    Remotely calls given method with given params.
    :param: method string with fully qualified method name
    :param: params dict with parameters of remotely called method
    :param: token CSRF token is always required except login method. Use method "Session.login" to obtain this token.
    """
    data = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": method, "params": params}

    req = urllib.request.Request(url=server + '/admin/api/jsonrpc/')
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    if token is not None:
        req.add_header('X-Token', token)

    httpResponse = opener.open(req, json.dumps(data).encode())

    if httpResponse.status == 200:
        body = httpResponse.read().decode()
        return json.loads(body)


session = callMethod("Session.login", {"userName": username, "password": password, "application": {"vendor":"Kerio", "name":"Control Api Demo", "version":"8.4.0"}})
token = session["result"]["token"]

sessions = callMethod("Users.get",
                      {"query": {
                                  "fields": [
                                      "id",
                                      "loginName",
                                      "fullName",
                                      "description",
                                      "authType",
                                      "itemSource",
                                      "isEnabled",
                                      "isPasswordReversible",
                                      "emailAddresses",
                                      "emailForwarding",
                                      "userGroups",
                                      "role",
                                      "itemLimit",
                                      "diskSizeLimit",
                                      "consumedItems",
                                      "consumedSize",
                                      "hasDomainRestriction",
                                      "outMessageLimit",
                                      "effectiveRole",
                                      "homeServer",
                                      "migration",
                                      "lastLoginInfo",
                                      "accessPolicy"
                                  ],
                                  "start": 0,
                                  "limit": 200,
                                  "orderBy": [
                              {
                                  "columnName": "loginName",
                                  "direction": "Asc"
                              }
                          ]
                      },
                       "domainId": Example:"keriodb://domain/908c1118-94ef-49c0-a229-ca672b81d965"
                       },
                      token)
    try:
        user_names = []
        for user in users["result"]["list"]:
            print(user["fullName"], " (", user["loginName"], ")", sep="")
            user_names.append(user["fullName"])
        call_method("Session.logout", {}, token)
        return users

    except KeyError:
        print('Error: {}'.format(users['error']['message']))
        call_method("Session.logout", {}, token)
        return None
```